# Oracle trigger update of column's value in Table1 after DML on column in Table2

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

friends!
I have two tables (tb_1, tb_2).

```
SQL> DESC tb_1;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- -----------
 PK_ID                                     NOT NULL NUMBER
 SUM_QUANTITY                                       NUMBER

SQL> DESC tb_2;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- -----------
 FK_ID                                              NUMBER
 QUANTITY                                           NUMBER
```

The column FK_ID - foreign key on the column PK_ID.
The column SUM_QUANTITY - sum of values in the column QUANTITY for specific pk_id

For example:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM tb_1;
 PK_ID SUM_QUANTITY
------ ------------
     1            8
     2           18
     3            2

SQL> SELECT * FROM tb_2;
FK_ID   QUANTITY
----- ----------
    1          1
    1          3
    1          4
    2          5
    2          6
    2          7
    3          1
    3          1
```

I want to auto update value in tb_1 in the column SUM_QUANTITY after 
DML (INSERT, UPDATE OF quantity, DELETE) operation in tb_2 for specific PK_ID!

I've created trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t_aiud
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF quantity OR DELETE ON tb_2
BEGIN
UPDATE tb_1 SET sum_quantity =  (SELECT sum(quantity) FROM tb_2 WHERE tb_1.pk_id = tb_2.fk_id);
END;
```

It works for ALL pk_id in table tb_1! So, how can I auto update value in tb_1 in the column SUM_QUANTITY for specific pk_id after DML operation?

Thank you!

Comment: to restrict fk_id use WHEN clause. To update for particular pk_id have a where clause in the update.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution here?  I am facing the same scenario.

Answer (score 3):

You can't, easily, if you want to refer to the table data. If you try to restrict the update based on `where tb1_1.pk_id = :new.fk_id` you'd have to make it a `for each row` trigger, and then you'll get [a mutating table error](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/5432/847), which can be coded around but it's not pretty or pleasant, or usually necessary.

What you're doing now will work up to a point, but you'll get unpredictable results if two people modify `tb_2` at the same time, even if they are not working with the same `fk_id`, as the trigger firing for each of them will only see their own changes - so the `sum_quanity` may end up with the wrong value. If you insert your three records into `tb_1`:

```
insert into tb_1 values (1, 0);
insert into tb_1 values (2, 0);
insert into tb_1 values (3, 0);
commit;
```

And then insert the first seven `tbl_2` rows in one session without committing yet:

```
insert into tb_2 values (1, 1);
insert into tb_2 values (1, 3);
insert into tb_2 values (1, 4);
insert into tb_2 values (2, 5);
insert into tb_2 values (2, 6);
insert into tb_2 values (2, 7);
insert into tb_2 values (3, 1);

select * from tb_1;

     PK_ID SUM_QUANTITY
---------- ------------
         1            8 
         2           18 
         3            1
```

and then in another session insert the final row:

```
insert into tb_2 values (3, 1);
commit;
```

... this will block until the first session is committed, then this insert will happen, but the totals will be wrong:

```
commit;
select * from tb_1;
     PK_ID SUM_QUANTITY
---------- ------------
         1
         2
         3            1
```

It will sort itself out on subsequent modifications, but can be wrong at any given time.

You could update `tb_1` directly, based on the values being modified:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t_aiud
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF quantity OR DELETE ON tb_2
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE tb_1
  SET sum_quantity = sum_quantity
    + NVL(:NEW.quantity, 0) - NVL(:OLD.quantity, 0)
  WHERE pk_id = NVL(:NEW.fk_id, :OLD.fk_id);
END;
/
```

... which doesn't need to query the table the trigger is on, so doesn't get the mutating table error; but that will also block if two sessions are modifying data for the same key.

Unless this is always going to be a single-user system, which is unlikely, you'd be better off either calculating the sum on the fly with a view that joins the two tables together, or for larger volumes of data, having a materialised view which maintains the total for you.

Comment: Hi Alex and thank you! I had the same opinion, but Guneli's solutions works..hmmm

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t_aiud
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF quantity OR DELETE ON tb_2
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
  UPDATE tb_1
  SET sum_quantity =
    (SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM tb_2 WHERE tb_1.pk_id = tb_2.fk_id
    )
  WHERE pk_id=:NEW.fk_id;
  COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: `:NEW.pk_id` is invalid. In where clause`:NEW.fk_id` from tb_2 is valid

Comment: Thanks, Guneli and Rock'em! PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION is a key, hm.

Comment: But the autonomous trigger can't see the data you just modified, so the totals don't change? ([Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/22fd3/1))